# if statement doesn't work on php/html/javascript. Always false

Tags: javascript, php

I'm having trouble with the following code.
Why when I test if the $date variable, the if statement the return is always true?
The goal of the code is check if the $date variable is empty when I load for the first time the page. If the page was loaded for the first time, the $date variable will return the current date, if I selected a date form the FORM, it will load the same page and the variable $date will be the selected date.

```
        <form action="#" method="POST">
            <p>Select date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" style="display: inline !important; width: 100px;">
                <input type="submit" value="Ok"></p>
                    <?php
                    //Variable to return the value of datepicker (calendar)
                        if (empty($date)) { //condition to check if the $date variable is empty, if empty select current date and send value to another php script
                            $date=date("Y-m-d")."%";    //select current date
                            $_SESSION['sending_date'] = $date;
                        } else{// if the value of date was selected, send variable value to another php script
                                $_SESSION['sending_date'] = $_POST['datepicker'] . "%";
                            }   
                    ?>
                <div id="draw_chart"></div> 
        </form>
```

Comment: where are you setting `$date`?

Comment: I never set the $date variable. Where I should set the variable?

Comment: the variable will always be refreshed on every run, you should pull it out of the session!

Comment: Maybe `if (empty($_SESSION['date']))`

Comment: Can you provide an example? I didn't understand what you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to set `$_SESSION['sending_date']` if `$_POST['datepicker']` is empty.

Based on that assumption, the revised if statement should be: `if (empty($_POST['datepicker']))`

Comment: Thank  you. It works.

Comment: No problem. Could you click on the check mark by the side to mark the question as answered?